# How can i get the rest of a division in Godot 3.1?

Tags: godot, gdscript, integer-division

I want to get the rest of a big number if I divide it by 100, and I can't find anything. Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

I presume you're using GDScript to interact with Godot?  Try this:

```
var my_remainder = my_big_number % 100
```

I found the `%` operator in [the Operators section of the documentation](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#operators).

Comment: That there is called the modulo operator, and the `%` character is how it is represented in many popular programming languages.